# Angular with Tailwind fails to build prod

Tags: angular, tailwind-css

I'm using Angular 11 with Tailwind 2. I'm not using custom webpack and postCSS, but I've tried that as well, and it was giving me the same error.

So the problem is when I try to build the prod version of the app, it gives me the following error:

```
Generating browser application bundles (phase: building)...An unhandled exception occurred: styles.add0c6b01f26781b3fec.css D:\Dev\Angular\project\styles.add0c6b01f26781b3fec.css:1344:16: Missed semicolon
See "C:\Users\farka\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-IzKrHt\angular-errors.log" for further details
```

It only happens with `@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';`. Without the utilities import, the build completes.

If I turn off the minifying in the angular.json it also builds.

```
                    "configurations": {
                      "production": {                            
                        "optimization": {
                            "scripts": true,
                            "styles": {
                                "minify": false,
                                ...
                            }
                        },
```

The error log showing me this:

```
[error] Error: styles.add0c6b01f26781b3fec.css D:\Dev\Angular\project\styles.add0c6b01f26781b3fec.css:1344:16: Missed semicolon
    at D:\Dev\Angular\project\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\plugins\optimize-css-webpack-plugin.js:98:48
    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
```

If anyone could give me some idea of how I could fix that, that would be awesome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. I'll write down my process of how I found it, maybe it will be helpful for others stuck on a similar issue.

So as the prod build was successful without minifying the CSS I figured that it should be something around that. I check and Angular uses the nanoCSS PostCSS plugin to minify the CSS. I compiled the prod build and used the CSS output and pasted it in https://cssnano.co/playground and tried to minify it. Turned out I had the following line in my tailwind.config.js file:

```
theme: {
    extend: {
        boxShadow: { 'add-to-fav-card-container': 'box-shadow: 0 0 0.625rem 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)', }
```

As you can see I was extending the default theme's boxShadow properties with my custom one, and accidentally wrote 'box-shadow: 0 0 0 ...' instead of only the value. This was not caught my nor my IDE's attention.